# How to run `wx python` in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, wxpython

How to run `wx Python` module in Jupyter notebook and execute the code successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the `%gui wx` magic? It will create an `wx.App` object and integrate the wx mainloop with the Jupyter message handling loop. Notice that I didn't need to create a `wx.App` nor run `MainLoop` in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: the solution seems ok but when we run the code outside Jupyter notebook we need `wx.app` and `mainloop`. Am i right?

Comment: Yes. Code run within a Notebook typically isn't really meant for running standalone, but with a bit of code organization you can probably share code between the two.

Comment: When I try this, `print(wx.GetApp())` returns `None` and then the kernel crashes. It seems that it's actually crashing on the `%gui wx` step, so it never builds `wx.app`. Any idea why this is causing the kernel to crash? Nothing useful was printed to the terminal.

Comment: @RobinDunn: This is spectacular, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

We need to execute 4th line and 5th line separately.

[image]